# Conditional Styling For Autoplacement Changes in CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I am looking for a way to detect when the `grid-auto-flow` css property has been engaged and apply conditional styling, eg. larger font-size.

Full demo example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ymcwig?file=style.css) (as you can't resize in Stackoverflow's snippet container).

Is this possible using just CSS? Or am I going the wrong way about solving this?

I need the `font-size: x` to get larger when the screen gets smaller. I'd rather refrain from introducing any javascript (and or) media queries into this.

*unless there's a media-query that can detect this change*

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  color: rgb(107, 107, 107);
  font-size: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(240px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-flow: row;
}

main section:first-child h1 {
  padding-left: var(--page-left-padding);
}

main section article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

main section article div {
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 0.3em;
}

main section article div:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 3em;
}

main section article p {
  font-size: 1em;
}

ul,
li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <h1>If you resize, this text will be positioned above, not to the side.</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <article>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <div>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
        <li>consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
        <li>Praesent iaculis tempor</li>
        <li>nulla nec rutrum. Donec eu purus</li>
        <li>uspendisse potenti</li>
        <li>libero sem sollicitudin</li>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <p>Mauris sem tortor</p>
      <div>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
        <li>consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
        <li>Praesent iaculis tempor</li>
        <li>nulla nec rutrum. Donec eu purus</li>
        <li>uspendisse potenti</li>
        <li>libero sem sollicitudin</li>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Have you considered any frameworks such as bootstrap?

Comment: @MakisMilas Nope. I don't want to pull in entire frameworks for detecting a change in the grid.

Comment: Then I guess you can work with 'vw' instead of em's. Because then the font-size will be dependent on the viewport width

Comment: Nope, then the size will get smaller, not bigger. Even an alg like `calc(1/ (1/3vw/2));` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

To detect changes of screen width use media-query, they are made for this. And you can set any `font-size` according to your media breakpoints. I agree, media breakpoints can't detect changes in number of columns while using `grid-template-columns` `auto-fit`. But it's CSS friendly.

To connect `grid-template-columns` count and font size you can use following way.

```
main {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
main section:first-child h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
}

@media (max-height: 475px) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
  main section:first-child h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
}
```

Or, if you want to count columns and detect changes caused by `auto-fit` - this is task for JavaScript.

Made simple JavaScript, which counts the number of blocks in first column, comparing their `offsetTop`. Then we gat the number of columns in CSS variable `--cols` and can use it anywhere we like, for instance `font-size: calc(36px / var(--cols));`

```js
countCols();

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  countCols();  
});

function countCols() {
  let cols = 0;
  let mainOffsetTop = document.querySelector('main section').offsetTop; /* main offset top */
  let mainSections = document.querySelectorAll('main section'); 
  for (let i = 0; i < mainSections.length; i += 1) {
    /* (section offset top) and (main offset top) == for the first row elements */
    if((mainSections[i].offsetTop - mainOffsetTop) == 0) {
      cols++;
    } else {
      break;
    }    
  }
  // getting CSS variable in body
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--cols', cols);
}
```

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  color: rgb(107, 107, 107);
  font-size: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(240px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-flow: row;
}

main section:first-child h1 {
  padding-left: var(--page-left-padding);
  font-size: calc(36px / var(--cols));
}

main section article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

main section article div {
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 0.3em;
}

main section article div:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 3em;
}

main section article p {
  font-size: 1em;
}

ul,
li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <h1>If you resize, this text will be positioned above, not to the side.</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <article>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <div>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
        <li>consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
        <li>Praesent iaculis tempor</li>
        <li>nulla nec rutrum. Donec eu purus</li>
        <li>uspendisse potenti</li>
        <li>libero sem sollicitudin</li>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <p>Mauris sem tortor</p>
      <div>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
        <li>consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
        <li>Praesent iaculis tempor</li>
        <li>nulla nec rutrum. Donec eu purus</li>
        <li>uspendisse potenti</li>
        <li>libero sem sollicitudin</li>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Updated an answer with @media solution. Your task can be solved only using `media` or  via JavaScritp, both can detect some changes on page, because they was designed to do it. I can't imagine any plain CSS solution for dynamic changes detection.